# SQL get most recent joined record

Tags: mysql, sql

I've the following tables:

chat: chatId, jobId

chat_message: userId, chatId, message, created_at

chat_user: chatId, userId

Am trying to get the last message sent by a specific user for all chats he's a part of.
This is what I have so far (left join for debugging on null):

```
SELECT c.chatid,
       m.message
FROM   chat AS c
       INNER JOIN chat_user AS cu
               ON cu.chatid = c.chatid
       LEFT JOIN (SELECT *
                   FROM   chat_message
                   WHERE  chat_message.userid = 6
                   ORDER  BY created_at DESC
                   LIMIT  1) AS m
               ON m.chatid = c.chatid
WHERE  cu.userid = 6;
```

The problem with this query is that the LIMIT 1 makes chat_message results null beyond the first row of results.

Removing the limit returns the data but am getting all the messages vs just the latest one.

What am I missing here? I feel like the LIMIT might be in the wrong place. I also tried the following alternative with no success:

```
SELECT c.chatid,
       m.message,
       m.userid
FROM   chat AS c
       INNER JOIN chat_user AS cu
               ON cu.chatid = c.chatid
LEFT JOIN chat_message as m
       ON  m.chatid = c.chatid
       AND m.created_at = (SELECT MAX(created_at) from chat_message)
WHERE  cu.userid = 6;
```

Expected:

```
chatid message userid
1   'Last message 1'    6
2   'Last message 2'    6
```

Actual:

```
chatid message userid
2   'Last message 2'    6
1   null null
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Am trying to get the last message sent by a specific user for all chats he's a part of.

```
SELECT cm.chatid, cm.message, cm.userid
FROM chat c JOIN
     chat_message cm
     ON m.chatid = cm.chatid
WHERE c.userid = 6 AND
      cm.created_at = (SELECT MAX(cm2.created_at)
                       FROM chat_message cm2
                       WHERE cm2.chatid = cm.chatid
                      );
```

To optimize performance, I would recommend indexes on:

- `chat_message(chatid, created_at)`
- `chat(userid, chatid)`

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `row_number()` window function to get last messages.

```
SELECT chatid, message, userid
FROM (
    SELECT chatid,
           message,
           userid,
           row_number() over(partition by userid, chatid order by created_at desc) rn
    FROM chat_message 
) t
WHERE userid = 6 AND rn = 1;
```

Answer (score 0):

> ...get the last message sent by a specific user for all chats he's a
> part of

You can find all the columns that you want to select in the table `chat_message`, so I don't see the reason for the joins.

Use `FIRST_VALUE()` window function:

```
SELECT DISTINCT
       chatid, 
       FIRST_VALUE(message) OVER (PARTITION BY chatid ORDER BY created_at DESC) message, 
       userid
FROM chat_message
WHERE userid = 6;
```